# Does Bouncy Castle actually provide underlying implementation for the Cipher Suites in org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.CipherSuite?

Tags: .net, bouncycastle

I am trying to use Bouncy Castle's DefaultTlsClient to interact with a server that only uses the cipher suite `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8`.
In searching through Bouncy Castle source code I came across the abstract DefaultTlsClient and thought I might be able to use it and override the `GetCipherSuites`method like such:

```cs
public override int[] GetCipherSuites()
{
    return new int[]
    {
        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8
    };
}
```

However I am not sure Bouncy Castle actually implements the suite, as the program crashes with a failed handshake(40) being emitted from the client after the Server finishes its hello - the 40 I believe should be a failed cipher suite negotiation error. So the order of TLS messages: client hello with CCM_8 cipher suite offered `->` server hello with CCM_8 cipher suite offered back `->` Alert Handshake failure(40) from client to server.

If I use more common ciphers when overriding `GetCipherSuites()` my implementation talks with other TLS servers like Google just fine, but the server I need to talk with only uses CCM_8.

Does Bouncy Castle TLSClient actually work with all the suites in the constant class `CipherSuite`: http://docs.glngn.com/latest/api/org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/CipherSuite.html?
Or does it rely on the OS to provide?

Moreover just trying find a way to to TLS in dotnet with `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` and x509 certificates. Libraries that I've found use only preshared keys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Bouncy Castle TLSClient can use uncommon/non os cipher suites:
I was able to create another CCM_8 server for testing with Openssl's s_server:
`openssl s_server -cert ./selfsigned.pem -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8  -www`
and my Bouncy Castle TLSClient was able to key exchange with it. So its just a bug in how I am using Bouncy Castle to create certificates for the TLSClient's certificate. (You can use the `-Verify` parameter in Openssl s_server to do a TLS certificate request and force the client to reply with a certificate or fail with if none is provided)